# Importing an excel file on a server into another excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to import an excel file hosted on a server into a workbook. This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub ranker()
'
' ranker macro
'

'
    Range("Ranker!A10:Ranker!Z100").ClearContents
    URL = Range("url!F2" & i).Text
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "FINDER;" & URL _
        , Destination:=Range("Ranker!$A$1:$Z$100"))
        .Name = "ranker"
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("'MTD SAR$'")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The only issue I have is that it pops up the following dialog box.

[dialog  box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKvCa.jpg)

I need to select the option 'MTD SAR$' every time. Can I select this option within the vba code to avoid the dialog box? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the `querytable` method having the ability to specify the sheet you want. I have got around this using OLEDB. Here's an example:

```
Sub Excel_QueryTable()

    Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnString As String
    Dim SQL As String

    Dim qt As QueryTable

    ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\SubFile.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False"
    Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
    oCn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    oCn.Open

    SQL = "Select * from ['MTD SAR$']"

    Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRS.Source = SQL
    oRS.ActiveConnection = oCn
    oRS.Open

    Set qt = Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=oRS, _
Destination:=Range("Ranker!$A$1"))

    qt.Refresh

    If oRS.State <> adStateClosed Then
        oRS.Close
    End If


    If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
    If Not oCn Is Nothing Then Set oCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is what I used, tweaked of course: [Query table with Excel as Data Source](http://vbadud.blogspot.com.au/2007/12/query-table-with-excel-as-data-source.html)